# AKPlayer crashes when playing from buffer on channelCount condition

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, audiokit

I struggle to make the following scenario work as expected (code will be provided below).

1. Record my microphone input  and store an `AVAudioPCMBuffer` in memory, this is done with `AVAudioPCMBuffer` extension method `copy(from buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, readOffset: AVAudioFrameCount = default, frames: AVAudioFrameCount = default)`. **I indeed get the buffer at the end of my recording**.
2. When record is ended pass the buffer to `AKPlayer` and play. Here is a code snippet to demonstrate what I do (I know it is no the full app code, if needed I can share it):

.

```
private var player: AKPlayer = AKPlayer()
self.player.buffering = .always

// in the record complete callbak:
self.player.buffer = self.bufferRecorder?.pcmBuffer
self.player.volume = 1
self.player.play()
```

- please note that the plater is connected to a mixer which is eventually connected to the AudioKit output.

when I inspect and debug the application I could see the buffer is with the correct length, and all my output/input setup uses the same processing format (sample rate, channels, bitrate etc) as well as the buffer recorded, but still my app crashes on this line:

```
2018-10-28 08:40:32.625001+0200 BeatmanApp[71037:6731884] [avae] AVAEInternal.h:70:_AVAE_Check: 
required condition is false: [AVAudioPlayerNode.mm:665:ScheduleBuffer: (_outputFormat.channelCount == buffer.format.channelCount)]
```

when I debug and walk through the AudioKit code I can see that the breaking line is on `AKPlayer+Playback.swift` on `line 162` on the method: `playerNode.scheduleBuffer`

more information that could be helpful:

- the buffer recorded is 16 seconds long.
- when I tried to pass the buffer straight to the player node in the tap method it seems as it worked, I did hear a delay from mic to speaker but it indeed played back.
- I tried call prepare on the player before play method invoked, no help

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this was super uncool debugging session. I had to investigate the `AVAudioEngine` and how this kind of scenario could be done there, which of course not the final result I was looking. This quest helped me to understand how to solve it with `AudioKit` (half of my app is implemented using `AudioKit`'s tools so it doesn't make sense to rewrite it with `AVFoundation`).

**`AFFoundation` solution:**

```
private let engine = AVAudioEngine()
private let bufferSize = 1024
private let p: AVAudioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()

let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
} catch {
    print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
}

let inputNode = self.engine.inputNode
engine.connect(inputNode, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0))
// !!! the following lines are the key to the solution.
// !!! the player has to be attached to the engine before actually connected
engine.attach(p) 
engine.connect(p, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)) 

do {
    try engine.start()
} catch {
    print("could not start engine \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

recordBufferAndPlay(duration: 4)
```

`recordBufferAndPlay` function:

```
func recordBufferAndPlay(duration: Double){
    let inputNode = self.engine.inputNode
    let total: Double = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().sampleRate * duration
    let totalBufferSize: UInt32 = UInt32(total)

    let recordedBuffer : AVAudioPCMBuffer! = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0), frameCapacity: totalBufferSize)

    var alreadyRecorded = 0
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 256, format: inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)) {
        (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in
        recordedBuffer.copy(from: buffer) // this helper function is taken from audio kit!
        alreadyRecorded = alreadyRecorded + Int(buffer.frameLength)
        print(alreadyRecorded, totalBufferSize)
        if(alreadyRecorded >= totalBufferSize){
            inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
            self.p.scheduleBuffer(recordedBuffer, at: nil, options: .loops, completionHandler: {
                print("completed playing")
            })
            self.p.play()
        }
    }
}
```

**`AudioKit` solution:**

So in the AudioKit solution these line should be invoked on your AKPlayer object. Note that this should be done before you actually start your engine.

```
self.player.buffering = .always
AudioKit.engine.attach(self.player.playerNode)
AudioKit.engine.connect(self.player.playerNode, to: self.mixer.inputNode, format: AudioKit.engine.inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0))
```

than the record is done pretty similarly to how you would have done it in AVAudioEngine, you install a tap on your node (microphone or other node) and record the buffer of PCM samples.